# Hide website from search engine visibility

Tags: seo, webserver

I made a web portal for internal office use. Since its an internal application, we don't need to open it into public, already have the login system. Since we need to connect all of our offices across the country we have to put this online.

My question is how to hide this site from search engine. Heard that a ".htaccess" file will do the job . Can any please advise ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a working login system, seach engines won't be able to see anything other than the landing/login page.

.htaccess would allow you to use Apache's password protection, but if you already have a login system, this won't do much for you.

You should create a robots.txt if you want well-behaved search engines to ignore your entire page. Contents like the following in robots.txt at your site root will make web crawlers ignore your entire site.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: oh thank you very much .. I will do this